# Exist a Java recyclerView?

Tags: java

im making a chat application, like telegram desktop client. But I don't know what object I have to use to print the users list. I need to click into a user and open the chat. In android this object is a recyclerView and in java? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using Swing or some other toolkit?

Comment: I depends on which GUI framework you're going to use. Swing, JavaFX or maybe something else? Could you specify it in your question, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask